# React-Spring too lazy with amount number of lists

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I use React-Spring in my app.
use Transition to add animation when components mount or unmount.
less then 20 lists, it work well, but more then 25 lists, it work too lazy or freeze.
I try to reproduce on codesandbox, but it has no problem.

Is there anything to solve this problem?

cords on sandbox are almost same as my apps code.

here is test on sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-work-test-0qill
and this is App test page:
https://if-then-planning.com/spring-test/

Comment: Is there an example where it is not working properly?

Comment: Peter, Thanks for your comment. 
https://if-then-planning.com/spring-test/ 
This link Page, On my device, list can't display properly. 
if reduce lines of list, less then 10 maybe, it works.
Should I up codes?  It may be too long, it contain some components.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without reproducing with code. There are issues with transition. Try the newest version. You can even try the version v9 (still in beta). But it has slightly different interface. The documentation for v9 is here: https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/

Comment: Thanks for Your Suggestion.
I will try to use v9 of React-Spring.
This component may be too much re rendering when list create.
Im not sure, however, I will try to change to v9 and to reduce rerendering.